# Error on boot "could not write bytes, broken pipe"

Tags: 12.04, screen, pipe

Each time i boot my Ubuntu just before showing login screen i get a error message after "could not write bytes, broken pipe".
Does anyone know why is this happening is there any problem with my installation?
I have Ubuntu 12.04